# Using Elmah with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, elmah

I am using jQuery to invoke page methods for my AJAX calls using $.Ajax. This works very well, and is very lightweight. However, I have noticed that when an exception is thrown from the .NET code, Elmah just logs it as a File Not Found exception, or will not log anything at all, rather than logging the actual exception that was thrown. Is there a way to get Elmah to pick up these exceptions? Do they need to be caught/rethrown? I'm sure it has something to do with the error handling in the JavaScript file, but I don't know where to go from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty certain that if ELMAH won't log properly in this senario without some modification.

May be worth asking the question here.

[link text](http://groups.google.com/group/elmah?pli=1)

Atif Aziz is generally quick to answer the questions